# How to solve the error after upgrading flutter?

Tags: flutter

After I update flutter the terminal in flutter gives out the following message,

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_colorpicker-0.4.0/lib/src/hsv_picker.dart:731:29: Error: The argument type 'PointerEvent' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PointerDownEvent'.
```

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you include the code-snippet that is producing this issue?

Comment: I would suggest updating the plugin, current version is 1.0.2, you are way behind.

Comment: Yep, I have also tried to update and there is a message said that the image_editor_pro must use with flutter_colorpicker v0.4.0

Comment: after updating flutter you also need to update plugins as well just run pub upgrade in your pubspec file id still facing issue then try pub outdated and update accordingly as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

- Goto `.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/` Folder.
- Delete folder `flutter_colorpicker-0.4.0`
- Try to Pug get again.

Thanks